# How to compare data from the same column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Panda's dataframe like the following:

[image: Countries dataframe]

And i want to get the countries where its PIB in 2007 was less than in 2002, but i couldn't code something to do that only using Pandas built in methods without use python iterations or something like that.
The most i've got is the following line:

```py
df[df[df.year == 2007].PIB < df[df.year == 2002].PIB].country
```

But i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Till now i've only used Pandas to filter data from different columns, but i don't know how to compare data from the same column, in this case the year.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, i'm new using these libraries which i need to learn machine learning and i really appreciate your support.
And just for future references for users who could have the similar problem, the answers that helped me a lot are the marked one and this one:


https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149984/11755598


Since there is explained the problem of trying to compare as i did with my code that raises the ValueError Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest create `Series` with index by `country` column, but is necessary same number of countries in `2007` and `2002` for compare Series with same index values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Afganistan', 'Zimbabwe', 'Afganistan', 'Zimbabwe'],
                  'PIB': [200, 200, 100, 300], 
                  'year': [2002, 2002, 2007, 2007]})
print (df)
      country  PIB  year
0  Afganistan  200  2002
1    Zimbabwe  200  2002
2  Afganistan  100  2007
3    Zimbabwe  300  2007
```

---

```
df = df.set_index('country')
print (df)
            PIB  year
country              
Afganistan  200  2002
Zimbabwe    200  2002
Afganistan  100  2007
Zimbabwe    300  2007

s1 = df.loc[df.year == 2007, 'PIB'] 
s2 = df.loc[df.year == 2002, 'PIB']
print (s1)
country
Afganistan    100
Zimbabwe      300
Name: PIB, dtype: int64

print (s2)
country
Afganistan    200
Zimbabwe      200
Name: PIB, dtype: int64

countries = s1.index[s1 < s2]
print (countries)
Index(['Afganistan'], dtype='object', name='country')
```

Another idea is first pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then seelct columns by years and compare with index in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.pivot('country','year','PIB')
print (df1)
year        2002  2007
country               
Afganistan   200   100
Zimbabwe     200   300

countries = df1.index[df1[2007] < df1[2002]]
print (countries)
Index(['Afganistan'], dtype='object', name='country')
```

Answer (score 3):

My strategy is using the pivot_table. There is an assumption that there are no two rows having the same ('country','year') pair. With this assumption, `aggfunc=np.sum` represents the only single `PIB` value.

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='PIB', index=['country'],
                    columns=['year'], aggfunc=np.sum)[[2002,2007]]
list(table[table[2002] > table[2007]].index)
```

The pivot_table looks like this:

[image: The pivot_table looks like this]

Comment: You are right. Using ```pivot``` is a better choice and aggregate is not needed. I will edit my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (considering that you want just the list of these countries):

```
[i for i in df.country if df[(df.country==i) & (df.year==2007)].PIB.iloc[0] < df[(df.country==i) & (df.year==2002)].PIB.iloc[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"country": "a", "PIB": 2, "year": 2002},
    {"country": "b", "PIB": 2, "year": 2002},
    {"country": "a", "PIB": 1, "year": 2007},
    {"country": "b", "PIB": 3, "year": 2007},
])
```

If I filter the two year 2002 and 2007, I got.

```
df_2002 = df[df["year"] == 2007]
out : 
  country  PIB  year
0       a    2  2002
1       b    2  2002

df_2007 = df[df["year"] == 2007]
out : 
  country  PIB  year
2       a    1  2007
3       b    3  2007
```

You want to compare the evolution of the PIB for each country.

Pandas is unaware of that, it tries to compare values but here based on the same index. Witch is not what you want, and it's impossible because the indexes are different.

So you just need to use `set_index()`

```
df.set_index("country",  inplace=True)
df_2002 = df[df["year"] == 2007]
out : 
         PIB  year
country           
a          1  2007
b          3  2007

df_2007 = df[df["year"] == 2007]
out : 
         PIB  year
country           
a          2  2002
b          2  2002
```

now you can make the comparison

```
df_2002.PIB > df_2007.PIB
out:
country
a     True
b    False
Name: PIB, dtype: bool

# to get the list of countries
(df_2002.PIB > df_2007.PIB)[res == True].index.values.tolist()
out : 
['a']
```